# Logistic regression VS ordinal regression using cumulative logits?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, logit, ordered-logit

What's the difference between a logistic regression and an ordinal regression using cumulative logits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpretation of ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89474/interpretation-of-ordinal-logistic-regression)

Answer (score 3):

*Logistic regression* is usually taken to mean binary logistic regression for a two-valued dependent variable $Y$.  *Ordinal regression* is a general term for any model dedicated to ordinal $Y$ whether $Y$ is discrete or continuous.  The *cumulative logit* model is a poorly formed term for the *proportional odds model*, also called the *ordinal logistic model*.  The terminology *cumulative logit* is poor for two reasons: there are no logits being accumulated (the model is stated in terms of cumulative *probabilities*), and the inventor of the term, McCullagh (1980), did not reference the inventors of the proportional odds model, Walker and Duncan (1967).  Sometimes you will see the full terminology *proportional odds ordinal logistic model*.

My RMS course notes go into more detail - see https://hbiostat.org/rms and https://fharrell.com/post/rpo