# How to build regression model in R for nested data and ordinal dependent variable?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, ordinal-data

I am looking at how some individual-level psychological variables relate to an organizational-level dependent variable. In this case, the dependent variable is the ranking of the organization (ordinal variable).

I understand that I need to use ordinal logistic regression. I came across R’s `polr` package mentioned [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/). But I am not sure if polr can account for the nested nature of my data: individuals nested in teams, and teams nested in organizations.

Is there a way to model the following: `y_ordinal ~ ind_psych1+ ind_psych2 + (1 + team_id/org_id)`?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you checked using the lme4 package with the function glmer? Your question seems to arise from not knowing that nested data is modeled through multilevel / mixed models or am I missing something?

Comment: Is not lme4 for linear mixed effects only? My dependent variable is ordinal.

Comment: The glmer function is for generalized linear mixed models, so it should be able to fit your model (although I haven't used such function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options for modeling ordinal outcome data when your data structure is multilevel. Among the options are the `clmm2` (cumulative link mixed models) [function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tutorial.pdf) within the `ordinal` package. This package fits [proportional odds cumulative logit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7720/how-to-understand-output-from-rs-polr-function-ordered-logistic-regression), which assume that the effect of x is the same for each cumulative odds ratio.

The proportional odds assumption can be relaxed with a non-proportional odds approach, which is available in the `mixor` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixor/vignettes/mixor.pdf). The default in `mixor` is to fit proportional odds cumulative logit models, but with the `KG=` option, you tell `mixor` how many of your predictors you would like to relax this assumption for. You can then run a likelihood ratio test using the `anova` command on the two models (proportional and non-proportional odds), which are nested models.

If you are interested in Bayesian approaches, you can use `brms`, which uses Stan to fit a literal cornucopia of ordinal multilevel models. See [this](https://psyarxiv.com/x8swp/) great introductory and how-to article from B$\ddot{u}$rkner & Vuorre.